# Suddenly, prints only go to queue

Tags: printing

New Linux user.  Old printer removed as not supported, replaced with HP Desktop 1000.  This has worked for several weeks.

Yesterday all attempts to print a document went to a queue, nothing prints out. Paper in place, power light on, front gate open, cables in place.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also having a similar problem with HP DeskJet 1xxx printer (don't remember the exact model). My understanding of the problem is that the printer requires a proprietary driver downloaded from HP website - which is supposed to happen automatically when the printer is detected, but the configuration script often fails - in particular, this is happening every time a new HPLIP version in installed by Update Manager.

To fix this, I run the configuration utility manually:

```
sudo hp-setup
```

This will ask you some questions (turn the printer off, turn the printer on etc.) and download the driver.

On some ocassions I had problems with running it in graphical mode - there's a command-line switch to make it use text mode, something like `sudo hp-setup -t`

Answer (score 0):

It may be paused(disabled). If you go to your printing console, and right click on ENABLED if it's not checked.

If that does not work you may need to install the HPLIP driver, update and reinstall the printer. Which is reall easy, just unplug the usb cable, delete it in the printing console,  and plug it back in and let the computer discover it again.